# Would sampling the decimal digits of $\pi$ generate a white noise signal?

Tags: stochastic-processes, random, pi, random-functions, noise

- Discrete r.v. $X = \pi(d)$ ([defined in another q of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3185934/490122)).
- Discrete r.v. $Y = X - 4.5$.

q1: Would it be incorrect to deduce $Y\sim U(-4.5,4.5)$ from $X\sim U(0,9)$?
q2: If you answered no to q1, please consider this...

- Since $Y$ is a [uniformly distributed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_uniform_distribution) r.v. centered @ $0$, $E\left[Y\right] = 0$.

If we started sampling $Y$ @ a constant rate (equal to $d$'s incrementation rate), the observed signal would satisfy the definition of "[white noise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/White_noise)"?

Comment: My understanding of a uniformly distributed random variable on, say, $(0,9)$ is that (among other things) it can take on any value between zero and nine, not just integer values, so the digits of pi can't possibly be uniformly distributed. If your definition restricts to integer values, then $Y$ can't be uniformly distributed, since it takes on half-integer values. And "white noise" is surely much more restrictive than a uniformly distributed random variable. The digits of $.01234567890123456789\dots$ give a uniform distribution, but do they give white noise?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I used the discrete version of the uniform distribution (I will edit q to provide a link) & my "white noise" conditions were based on this wiki quote: "Any distribution of values is possible (although it must have zero DC component). Even a binary signal which can only take on the values 1 or –1 will be white if the sequence is statistically uncorrelated".

Comment: I don't know what a "DC component" is, but as far as "statistically uncorrelated" goes, the example I gave gives a uniformyl distributed random variable since each value occurs with probability one-tenth, but it is statistically highly correlated, so it's not white noise.

Comment: @GerryMyerson "DC component" refers to the requirement that the sample mean be equal to 0. That is why I defined Y in the way that I did (rather than just sampling X directly).